# How to Make a Deep Nested Loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, nested-loops

For some reason I'm drawing a blank right now. I want to make a list that represents all the possible outcomes for the last week of football (16 total games).

There should be 2^16 (65536) outcomes excluding tie scenarios. I know I could just make 16 nested for loops with a range length of 2 in each loop, but there has to be a better way.

I want each game to essentially be a list (0 for loss, 1 for win).

Example of an outcome in a list of length 65536:

Index 0 (16 total games):

> [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]

The next index might look the same (for example), except the last one is flipped

> [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]]

Each index is a unique outcome of the week.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 65536 states, it can be represented by an integer between 0 and 65535, then converted to binary, and converted to the list you wanted.

Here's some code that works:

```
for i in range(65536):
    s = "{:016b}".format(i)
    l = [[1, 0] if ch == "1" else [0, 1] for ch in s]
    print(s)
```

The first line enumerates all integers from 0 to 65535.
The second line converts the number to 16-digit binary number (e.g. `0101010101010101`)
The third line maps each digit to `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]` and creates the list you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is a better way to do this. You can simply use the `product` function from `itertools` which is exactly equivalent to what you are trying to do. The [docs on it are here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

It's as easy as:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> outcomes = list(product(range(2), repeat=16))
>>> print(len(outcomes))
65536
>>> print(outcomes[0])
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> print(outcomes[10000])
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

You'll note that this doesn't give you the `[0, 1]` pairs you were expecting, but obviously since there's only two teams in each game just consider the number shown at each position to be the score of the first team and you can infer the score of the other team to be the opposite of that.